# Trying to erase all the undefined nodes in a vector C++

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, erase

I have a dictionary program that supposed to delete from the `vector` in it all the undefined nodes (nodes that I did not declare the value to them, keys only);

---

**Dict.h**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Node.h"
using namespace std;

template <class K, class V>
class Dict {
public:
    Dict();
    vector<Node<K,V>> vec;
    V& operator[](const K &str);


};

template class Dict<string, int>;
```

---

**Dict.cpp:**

```
#include "Dict.h"

template <typename  K, typename V>
Dict<K,V>::Dict() {};

template <typename K, typename V>
V & Dict<K,V>::operator[](const K &str) {
    int i = 0,len = vec.size();
    while(i < len){
        if(this->vec[i].value == 0)
        {
            this->vec.erase(this->vec.begin() + i);
            len = this->vec.size();
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    Node<K,V> n;
    n.key = str;
    this->vec.push_back(n);

    return this->vec.back().value;
}
```

---

**Node.h**:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class K, class V>
class Node {
public:
    K key;
    V value;
    Node();
};

template class Node<string, int>;
```

---

**Node.cpp:**

```
#include "Node.h"

template <typename K, typename  V>
Node<K,V>::Node() {};
```

---

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Dict.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Dict<string,int> d;
    d["nod1"] = 5;
    d["node2"] = 7;
    d["node3"];
    d["node4"] = 8;
    d["node5"];
    for(int i = 0; i < d.vec.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << d.vec[i].value;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

in this main example, the output will be `5780`, but if I will declare `node5` to `9` for example, the output will be `5789`. that means the `[]` operator overloading function erases all the undefined nodes in the `vector` unless the last node if it's not defined.
I have tried to do the erase loop after adding the current node but it throws me an exception:

```
Process finished with exit code 139
```

Comment: are you reinventing `std::map`?

Comment: I didn't delve very much into what you are trying to do, but I see two bugs in this code: 1. `while(i < len){` in the loop body you erase elements, so vector become shorter, but len doesn't get updated, so you get out of range access (UB), you should use there `while (i < vec.size()) {`; 2. You do not initialize the Node::value (either in constructor or in-class), therefore the check ` if(this->vec[i].value == 0)` may not hit as expected.

Comment: len actually is updated as nodes get erased

Comment: `Node` should really be spelled `std::pair`

Comment: Didn't see. Then there is one bug.

Comment: @nicolai sp2danny I hope YoavLinder is doing this as an exercise and not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: no, i am doing an exrecise of templates, operator overloading and classes in cpp becuase i am learning the language.

Comment: and my problem here is only if the last element added is undefined then its not removed (if its the first/in the middle, it is removed)

Answer (score 1):

> in this main example, the output will be 5780

Thats pure luck since the constructor of your `class Node` doesn't initialize its members.

There is no point in removing "empty" nodes in `operator[]()` since if the currently added "key" has a defined (`!=0`) value or not can only be determined after the reference your `operator[]()` returns has a value `!=0` assigned to or not:

```
d["node3"];
// now it is known that "node3" has no value != 0
d["node4"] = 8;
// now it is known that "node4" has a value of 8
```

Also you should use `std::size_t` for indexes and sizes of objects in memory.

> i have tried to do the erase loop after adding the current node but it
>   throws me an exception: Process finished with exit code 139

Thats to be expected since a newly added "key" cannot have a value. So consider an empty `vector` with the first "key" added and its value being `0`. Your loop would remove it so the vector is empty again. Then you try `back().value()` on that empty vector which must crash.

Comment: i see what the problem is as you said the bac().value on an empty value. but how can i bypass that? i cant find a way to make it work otherwise

Comment: @YoavLinder use a dedicated function that removes "empty" keys.

Comment: i tried, i moved the while loop taht erases to a function but i cannot call it after i add an element because of the begin().value() line

Comment: @YoavLinder "i cannot call it after i add an element because of the begin().value() line" if you're talking about calling said function from inside your `operator[]()` you didn't understand the problem yet.

Comment: @YoavLinder the assignment of a possible value occures AFTER `operator[]()` has returned, so if a value is assigned to the reference returned can't be possible determined INSIDE `operator[]()`.

Comment: so where can i use the erase function/loop without calling another function in the main?

Comment: @YoavLinder you cannot use it before eg. `d["node3"];` or `d["node4"] = 8;` is completely evaluated. Again: it can't be known inside `operator[]()` if there will be a value assigned to the reference returned by it.

Comment: then where i can define it? i want the main to be the same as it is in the example above but it will output 578

Comment: @YoavLinder thats not possible.

Comment: i cant overload the [] operator and erase elements that are not defined?

Comment: @YoavLinder consider `d["node3"];` in this statement `d.operator[]("node3")` is called, it does its work and returns a reference to the newly added "node3" in the vector. Now, after `d.operator[]("node3")` returned one **could** assign a value to the returned reference or not. But since `d.operator[]("node3")` has already done its work and returned, `d.operator[]("node3")` cannot know if there will be a value assigned to the reference it returns.

Comment: so i have nothing to do with it or i can change somthing so it will work?

Comment: @YoavLinder not really. The version of `operaotr[]()` you have in your question takes care of "keys" not assigned a value, but it cannot determine if the current "key" being added will later have a value assigned so it will always be possible for the last "key" added to have no value assigned to it.